# Android & a library project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a library beside my main project in an android project.
How can I set compiler to it always compile library first and then compiles my main code?
Currently I have to compile two times on every build.

Comment: Have you set the main project to be dependent on the library? Do you have automatic build on? If you have, then Eclipse should take care of the builds automatically.

Answer (score 3):

To Add Library project to Your Project

1.If you have a jar file then place the jar file in the `libs` folder in your project.
then right click on it and `Build Path-->Add to Build Path`

2.If you have a library as a project then right click on your  Main project
`Properties-->Android-->Add` then select your library project(make sure here library projects with librariesonly appear)

3.if your library project is not appearing in this list then rigth click on your library project `Properties-->Android` tick `isLibrary` option there)

you can cjheck out the image like..

[image]

if you want to change the priority of your Library

Right Click on your Project `Build path--> Configure Build path --> Order and Export`

there you will see your library select your library click on `top` at the right side

the image is like below.

[image]

Comment: And what are check boxes beside each library?

Comment: I did this, now it doesn't say the apk build before, but still I have two compile two times to have my changes apply to app on mobile.

Comment: And it prompts this : Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared

Comment: ones check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146655/compiling-jars-and-add-them-to-android-project

Comment: i am using 19.0.3 build tools, and compiling with 4.4. I was getting same error Dx trouble writing, but after moving android private lib folder on top it started working. Thanks!!!